# How we can automate barclays order generation

Tags: automated-tests

I am stuck with automating REST API Barclay's order generation and processing.

I could automate the Barclays order generation, but while processing the Barclays order needs the card information. How we can mimic the card data filing through automation?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think you should try to condense a small example in (pseudo) code.